# Questions on GLIBC Heap Exploitation (House of Force)

Tags: heap-overflow, glibc

This is with reference to Max Kamper's video on GLIBC heap exploitation and these articles I read

- https://www.crow.rip/crows-nest/binexp/heap/house-of-force-i
- https://www.crow.rip/crows-nest/binexp/heap/house-of-force-i/house-of-force-ii

I have a few questions about the video and articles.

- Why is the formula for calculating the wrap around address the following?

```
def diff(x, y):
    return (0xffffffffffffffff - x) + y
```

Why use 0xffffffffffffffff to minus x and then plus y? How does this give us the difference in the distance? Why use 0xffffffffffffffff?

- When using __malloc_hook to execute the `system` function, how does the binary knows where is the argument for the function call? The pointer to the argument is located at `malloc((heap + 0x30) "")` but how does the function knows that its there and why `heap + 0x30`?